# How to stream video over UDP port with GStreamer from inside a Docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, containers, udp, gstreamer

I have created an image container that downloads, builds and installs GStreamer. After that when I run the container and I try to run a GStreamer command line like this

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=/home/Documents/video.mp4  ! decodebin !\
 videoconvert ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

I am not able to receive the streaming with the respective command from outside of the container:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc  port=5000 !\
 application/x-rtp,encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay !\
 jpegdec ! autovideosink
```

But when I run both commands outside of the container it works fine.

Anyone know how it could be made, please?

Obs:

- This is how I am running the container:

```
    docker build -t gstreamer-image . 

    docker run -it -p 127.0.0.1:5000:5000/udp 3c1b4d08122e
```

- I tried running this way also:

```
docker run -it -p 127.0.0.1:5000:5000 3c1b4d08122e
```

and with the tag --network=host

Answer (score 0):

No need to figure out how to forward ports, just open a udp connection to the host directly:

Sender in docker container:

```
docker run -it --rm --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway gstreamer-image bash
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=host.docker.internal port=5000
```

Receiver on host:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! autovideosink
```